# TableViewController sections and rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController with custom section headers, since I have my `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` set to `return [self.uploads count];` and my `numberOfRowsInSection:` set to `return 1;` I get everything from my `viewForHeaderInSection:` set correctly when I run the app, but the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is always getting the same values when I run the app, since indexPath is only getting 1 value (due to `numberOfRowsInSection:` returning 1).

In my headers I am getting the correct info changing but the cell is the same for every section:

Ex.

(Section 1) Username: John

(Cell 1) Lastname: Smith

(Section 2) Username: Maria

(Cell 1) Lastname: Smith

(Section 3) Username: Michael

(Cell 1) Lastname: Smith

If I set the value of `numberOfRowsInSection` to `return [self.uploads count]` I get the following output:

Ex.

(Section 1) Username: John

(Cell 1) Lastname: Smith

(Cell 2) Lastname: Williams

(Cell 3) Lastname: Peters

(Section 2) Username: Maria

(Cell 1) Lastname: Smith

(Cell 2) Lastname: Williams

(Cell 3) Lastname: Peters

(Section 3) Username: Michael

(Cell 1) Lastname: Smith

(Cell 2) Lastname: Williams

(Cell 3) Lastname: Peters

What I want my real output to be is: 

(Section 1) Username: John

(Cell 1) Lastname: Smith

(Section 2) Username: Maria

(Cell 2) Lastname: Williams

(Section 3) Username: Michael

(Cell 3) Lastname: Peters

Any help please?

Edit:

Here is my code:

```
-(UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SectionHeader";
    UITableViewCell *headerView = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (headerView == nil){
        [NSException raise:@"headerView == nil.." format:@"No cells with matching CellIdentifier loaded from your storyboard"];
    }

    PFObject *audio = [self.uploads objectAtIndex:section];

    [self setBlurView:[AMBlurView new]];
    [[self blurView] setFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, [headerView bounds].size.width, [headerView bounds].size.height)];
    [[self blurView] setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
    [self.blurView setBlurTintColor:nil];
    [headerView addSubview:[self blurView]];
    self.blurView.layer.zPosition = -1;

    // Profile pic
    NSString *objectId = [audio objectForKey:@"uploader"];
    PFUser *user = [PFQuery getUserObjectWithId:objectId];

    PFFile *avatar = [user objectForKey:@"avatar"];
    [avatar getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            UIImageView *profileImage = (UIImageView *)[headerView viewWithTag:200];
            profileImage.image = image;

            CALayer * l = [profileImage layer];
            [l setMasksToBounds:YES];
            [l setCornerRadius:13.0];
        }
    }];

    // Name
    UILabel *name = (UILabel *)[headerView viewWithTag:201];
    name.text = [audio objectForKey:@"uploaderName"];

    // timestamp
    NSDate *created = [audio createdAt];
    self.timeIntervalFormatter = [[TTTTimeIntervalFormatter alloc] init];

    UILabel *timestampLabel = (UILabel *)[headerView viewWithTag:202];

    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [created timeIntervalSinceNow];
    NSString *timestamp = [self.timeIntervalFormatter stringForTimeInterval:timeInterval];
    [timestampLabel setText:timestamp];

    return headerView;
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [self.uploads count];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    PFObject *audio = [self.uploads objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UILabel *caption = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:207];
    caption.text = [audio objectForKey:@"caption"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: if those names are from an array, you'd probably have to use NSIndexPath -section, as the index of the name on your array of names (or self.uploads,if that's what it is) right?

Comment: That was it! thank you riadhluke!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try set lastNameLb in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    PFObject *audio = [self.uploads objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]; //indexPath.section

    UILabel *caption = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:207];
    caption.text = [audio objectForKey:@"caption"];

    return cell;
}
```

Note that, index is `indexPath.section`, not `indexPath.row`.

Answer (score 1):

In cellForRowAtIndexPath: you are only checking indexPath.row . indexPath has two values to check: indexPath.section and indexPath.row. Check the value of section property to select the correct "lastname" property.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm pretty new at using UITableViewCells, what would be the code to check indexPath.section? Does it go inside cellForRowAtIndexPath:?